# How to make faceted boxplots using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have the following data frames:

```
samples_i <- c("LAIV D0", "LAIV D3", "LAIV D7", "LAIV D0", "LAIV D3", "LAIV D7", 
"TIV D0", "TIV D3", "TIV D7", "TIV D0", "TIV D3", "TIV D7")

irisTag_i <- structure(c(0, 0, 0, 11.2672863636364, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 13.8881727272727, 
0, 0, 0), .Dim = c(2L, 7L), .Dimnames = list(c("HSP90B1", "DNAJB1"
), c("Neutrophil", "Tcell", "Monocyte", "Bcell", "NKcell", "PlasmaCell", 
"DendriticCell")))


SPVsR_i <- structure(c(0.1620678925564, -0.0609851972808482, -0.101082695275552, 
0.184268723991321, -0.0899021067853178, -0.0943666172060028, 
0.178289177586651, -0.0823892768809311, -0.0958999007057199, 
0.0331377432233005, 0.00289013805790048, -0.036027881281201, 
-0.0531973808347148, 0.0213528550009522, 0.0318445258337625, 
0.0179790366380429, 0.00347902775389391, -0.0214580643919368, 
-0.0136820170970586, 0.0142833182813199, -0.000601301184261278, 
0.0109856660204762, -0.00528600624634141, -0.00569965977413478, 
-0.0760171167711921, 0.0344372228755224, 0.0415798938956697, 
-0.114239469843063, 0.0217218301803764, 0.0925176396626868, -0.113283279031257, 
0.0424936766667866, 0.07078960236447, -0.14127024964406, 0.0595080054464686, 
0.0817622441975909, -0.0100499090500894, 0.0131491664210288, 
-0.00309925737093941, 0.101206058442775, 0.0231964804556542, 
-0.124402538898429, 0.00411785437964246, 0.0405556634613935, 
-0.044673517841036, 0.0720705616752313, -0.00782701824901867, 
-0.0642435434262126, 0.0753224665976433, -0.0323083061719772, 
-0.0430141604256661, -0.0654080281579984, 0.0124273486220488, 
0.0529806795359496, -0.0519970799923912, 0.00818146905729871, 
0.0438156109350925, 0.0200682008260364, -0.0466408267852637, 
0.0265726259592274, -0.0390251373720762, -0.0115216989414941, 
0.0505468363135703, 0.0321298528741327, -0.0151866963239294, 
-0.0169431565502034, -0.0310600302048482, 0.00718748395053659, 
0.0238725462543116, -0.0216937374381297, -0.00559429498828404, 
0.0272880324264137, 0.0288166559498562, -0.0173984873138801, 
-0.0114181686359761, -0.0176892628883129, -0.0235673738231865, 
0.0412566367114994, -0.00794904064609583, -0.000656094604392996, 
0.00860513525048881, -0.0538196455977893, 0.0200107051556589, 
0.0338089404421304), .Dim = c(12L, 7L), .Dimnames = list(c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"), c("Neutrophil", 
"Tcell", "Monocyte", "Bcell", "NKcell", "PlasmaCell", "DendriticCell"
)))
```

And with this code

```
par(mfrow=c(2,3), mai=c(1,0.4,0.4,0.1), omi=rep(0,4))
    for ( i in c(2:7)){
        # deliberately skip i=1
        # so we 2 x 3 can fit in image

        boxplot(SPVsR_i[,i]~as.factor(samples_i), outline=F, density=c(10,20,300),  las=2, yaxt="n", col=c(brewer.pal(3,"Blues"),
        brewer.pal(3, "Oranges")), density=c(10,20,300), at=c(1,2,3,5,6,7))
        title(colnames(irisTag_i)[i])
    }
```

I can make this image:

[image]

Using the same three data frames above, how can I use ggplot2 to produce the similar result?

I tried this but failed:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

nsamplesv <- cbind(SPVsR_i, samples_i,deparse.level=2)
nsamplesv_df <- as.data.frame.matrix(nsamplesv)
nsamplesv.m <- melt(nsamplesv_df,id.vars=c('samples_i'))
colnames(nsamplesv.m) <- c("samples",'celltype','score')

p <- ggplot(nsamplesv.m, aes(samples,score)) +geom_boxplot() +facet_wrap( ~ celltype)
p
```

Produces this image:

[image]

I don't know specifically how to:

- Fix the y-axis, with  fewer ticks and 3 decimals.
- Boxes don't show up. Each frame should have 6 boxes.
- Would like to color the boxes. Those with LAIV as blues, and TIV as yellows.
- Rotate x-axis 180 degree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a better way to reshape your data:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(RColorBrewer)

as_data_frame(SPVsR_i) %>% 
  bind_cols(data_frame(sample=samples_i)) %>% 
  gather(celltype, score, -sample) %>% 
  mutate(celltype=factor(celltype, levels=unique(celltype))) %>% 
  filter(!(celltype %in% c("Neutrophil"))) -> df
```

ggplot2 requires mapping aesthetics to data frames OR ensuring referenced variables are of the same length as the data you're using.

I've mimicked your desired output here but please consider respecting your viewers and not making them tilt their heads to read the X-axis labels. Boxplots really should also have (IMO) major Y-axis lines so it's easier for human brains to decode the values. It's not 100% necessary, but (again) the point is to aid in understanding.

You also don't note the free Y-axis scales on your plot and I don't here but that's also kinda horribad. Even with the Y-axis tick labels, you should do something to ensure folks aren't trying to compare across celltypes with the exact same scales (which they will by default/automatically as they're working to decode the plot but the extra labeling will force an extra processing step provided folks read said guidance).

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(sample, score))
p <- p + geom_boxplot(aes(fill=sample))
p <- p + scale_fill_manual(values=c(brewer.pal(3,"Blues"), brewer.pal(3,"Oranges")))
p <- p + facet_wrap(~celltype, scales="free")
p <- p + labs(x=NULL, y=NULL)
p <- p + theme_bw(base_size=10)
p <- p + theme(strip.background=element_blank())
p <- p + theme(strip.text=element_text(face="bold"))
p <- p + theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, vjust=0.5))
p <- p + theme(panel.grid.major.x=element_blank())
p <- p + theme(panel.grid.major.y=element_blank())
p <- p + theme(panel.grid.minor.y=element_blank())
p <- p + theme(panel.margin=margin(20,20,20,20))
p <- p + theme(plot.margin=margin(20,20,20,20))
p <- p + theme(legend.position="none")
p
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any reason to re-assign `p` at every row?